# Flutter align timestamp text on bubble chat message

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My chat bubble looks like this:

[image]

I want its timestamp to **stick to the right side** like the following:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Bubble(
        margin: BubbleEdges.only(
          top: 10,
          left: leftMargin,
          right: rightMargin,
        ),
        color: backgroundColor,
        nip: bubbleNip,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            content,
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(timeFormat01(timestamp)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

How do I do that?

## What doesn't work?

Using Row `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` or Align `alignment: Alignment.centerRight` leads to stretching all bubbles to max width.

[image]

Adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` to the Column will align all texts that are smaller than the timestamp text to the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IntrinsicWidth` and `Align` solved my issue.

Here is the result:

```
return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Bubble(
        margin: BubbleEdges.only(
          top: 10,
          left: leftMargin,
          right: rightMargin,
        ),
        color: backgroundColor,
        nip: bubbleNip,
        child: IntrinsicWidth( // <--- here
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              content,
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight, // <--- here
                child: Text(timeFormat01(timestamp)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Read more about `IntrinsicWidth` [use cases](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-intrinsicwidth-widget-examples) and [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html).

Note:

> This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired effect by combining `IntrinsicWidth` and `Align` on your formatted `Bubble` widget.

**Output:**

[image]

**Source:**

Read the comments for explanation.

```
void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: BubbleApp())),
      ),
    );

class BubbleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BubbleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      /// [ConstrainedBox] is used to provide the maximum width
      /// of any one chat bubble.
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        /// In this case, let's use 300.0, but
        /// you can use MediaQuery.of(context) and a percentage.
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          /// Populate [children] however you manage your state.
          children: const [
            BubbleMessage(
              message:
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                  " Aenean eleifend sed purus a tincidunt. Aenean varius erat "
                  " eget justo lacinia.",
            ),
            BubbleMessage(message: "kdo!"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the wrapper around your [Bubble] class.
class BubbleMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BubbleMessage({super.key, required this.message});

  final String message;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Size the [BubbleMessage] class to the intrinsic width of the child.
    return IntrinsicWidth(
      /// Replace [Card] with your [Bubble] class.
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

          /// This ensures that the column height only take up as
          /// much height as needed by the children.
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

          children: [
            /// This is your content.
            Text(message, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            const SizedBox(height: 5.0),

            /// This is your formatted time. We align it to the right.
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.now()),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `IntrinsicWidth` and `Align` solved my issue. The solution is simpler than it described here. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74506579/12695188

Answer (score 1):

wrap your timestamp with `Align` widget like this :

```
IntrinsicWidth(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              content,
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(timeFormat01(timestamp)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: That didn't help. It leads to the second example in my question Update :/

Comment: Oh I though you need content align to right too, I updated my answer, can u check it again

Comment: Alignment .right case the same problem as using Row .end

Comment: Okay if you don't want that, just wrap it inside a IntrinsicWidth, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Wrap timestamp text in Row and with mainaxisalignment set to end.

Comment: We can skip wrapping with unnecessary widget

Comment: This answer does not work properly for shorter texts. I have updated my question

Comment: wrap the message text with ConstrainedBox with minimum width. Everything else stays same.

Comment: The constrain minWidth depends on the timestamp width, which should be dynamic between different devices. How do I fit the minWidth to be the same as the timestamp?

Comment: no no. minWidth for text message. overall the column will have width of max of all of it's children. it will look ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,` on `Column`

```dart
 child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
           content,
```

Comment: More about [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: This answer does not work properly for shorter texts. I have updated my question

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you replace `Bubble`?  Also can you provide full sample scaffold ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: widget.isMyMessage! ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [ widget.isMyMessage! == true
                       ? Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                          child: Image.asset(
                                 icRead,
                                 height: 16,
                                 width: 16,
                                ),
                         )
                         : Container(),
                        timeData != null ? Text( timeForChatMsg( timeData ),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: fontSize12,
              color: widget.isMyMessage! ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
          )
        : Container(); ,
                        widget.isMyMessage! == false
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  icRead,
                                  color: primaryColor,
                                  height: 16,
                                  width: 16,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ],
                    )
```